# How do we know if aggregations on the SSAS cube are unused?

Tags: ssas, query-performance, string-aggregation, dmv

Sql server version: 2016
Is there a way to know if aggregation on the cube is unused ? I have tried to get the information on the DMVs **$system.discover_object_activity** (gives me **count** of aggregations on a partitions/measure groups being hit or missed) and **$system.discover_partition_stat** (aggregation name and its processed state). I have read articles on SSAS specific DMVs and challenges in joining the DMVs to get combine data from DMVs to get useful information.  But I am not able to get information if a aggregation is left unused, like a list of aggregations which have been used/unused

The cube which is being investigated has over 200 aggregations. It is cumbersome to manually go through each one of them and check for the combinations. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Tabular or Multidimensional?  And have you looked into SSAS extended events?

Comment: We are using multidimensional. You mean SSAS extended events in profiler ? .. Yes I have looked into events which give me aggregations information for the query execution. What we are more interested in, is a way to check if aggregations on the cube which are unused ... either through DMVs or any other way ....